# Cannot Retrieve Comments Of An Instagram Post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/comments/) documentation to retrieve all the comments under a post on Instagram. The access token I am generating to test this out has the following permissions:

- business_management
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments
- instagram_manage_messages
- pages_messaging
- pages_read_engagement
- ads_read
- ads_management
- pages_show_list

I have checked the `/{user_id}/permissions` endpoint, and the payload showed that all the above mentioned permissions have been granted. Yet whenever I try to hit the `{media_id}/comments` endpoint, I get the follwing response -

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Missing permission or capability",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AxiV4nvOp7tLFNFM-qBvuqJ"
  }
}
```

I cannot find any solution to this anywhere. I would really appreciate any suggestions about it.

Comment: I'ts a bug at the moment: [Unable to retrieve IG comments with a valid token](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/296153916339672/?join_id=fcc28768aa60c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a system error because two days ago I can list the comments, but today I got the exact same error. Most probably they will correct it.

Comment: I'ts a bug at the moment: [Unable to retrieve IG comments with a valid token](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/296153916339672/?join_id=fcc28768aa60c)